# Does this question make any sense - eigenvalues and norms

Tags: matrices, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, normed-spaces

Im having difficulties understanding this question:

show that if $b$ is an eigenvector of an invertible matrix $A$ with an eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and $\delta b$ is an eigenvector of $A$ with an eigenvalue $\lambda_2$ then:

$$\frac{||\delta x||}{||x||}=\frac{|\lambda_1|* ||\delta b||}{|\lambda_2|* ||b||}$$

does this question make any sense? Whats $x$? is it just any vector? and what is $||.||$? some random norm?

Comment: Yes $x$ is an arbitrary vector and $\|\cdot\|$ is the standard Euclidean norm

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If $x=A^{-1}b$, $\delta x=A^{-1}\delta b$, $Ab=\lambda_1b$, and $A\delta b=\lambda_2b$ (with $b\neq 0$ and $\delta b\neq 0$), then $x=b/\lambda_1$ and $\delta x=\delta b/\lambda_2$ and for any vector norm $\|\cdot\|$ we have $\|x\|=\|b\|/|\lambda_1|$ and $\|\delta x\|=\|\delta b\|/|\lambda_2|$.

Comment: Hey Pavel, I just wanted to question explained, not answered. But even still - I think they meant an arbitrary vector $x$. by saying $x=A^{-1}b$ you kinda defeated the entire point of the exercise :)

Comment: @OriaGruber Sorry, you should not ask "what is $x$" then. BTW if $x$ was arbitrary, what would then be $\delta x$? I was just deducing from the given data. Equation of the form "something arbitrary = something very unarbitrary" does not make much sense for me :-)

Comment: I am terribly sorry Pavel, perhaps I was misleading in my terms. "What is x" is not what the question said. It's what I am saying. I don't understand what $x$ is supposed to represent. and I agree with you that the question does not make much sense, hence why I asked it. the question word to word quote is "show that if $b$ is an eigenvector of an invertible matrix $A$ with eigenvalue $\lambda_1$ and $\delta b$ is an eigenvector with value $\lambda_2$ then $\frac{||\delta x||}{||x||} = \frac{|\lambda_1|*||\delta b||}{|\lambda_2|*||b||}"$ which makes no sense to me

Comment: @OriaGruber I understand now. Ok, so then the answer should be "no", or you could try to put a sense to the question by a proper definition of $x$ and $\delta x$.